# Is Magento2 really compatible for AngularJS?

Tags: magento2

Also, is Magento2 is still in beta version or stablised for handling Angularjs2 apps?

Please quote the cons and pros of using Magento2 in AngularJS2 project if used before.

Comment: please don't devote if no answer for this... answering this will definitely help many

Comment: @Mufaddal any idea on Magento2 and angularJS2?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 released 2.0.0 stable in November 2015.

Is it possible to run AngularJS with Magento? Sure - see for example this presentation: http://slides.com/rocwang/storefront#/

Comment: How abt Angular 1.x